# Datanucleus build time enhancement break class inheritance in Eclipse Java Editor

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, jdo, datanucleus

I'm developing an OSGi app using datanucleus as datastore platform.

My practice is putting all *model* (entity/persistent) classes in *api bundle* and keep the implementation in *impl bundle*, which is a good practice for anyone developing an OSGi app.

This is my simplified version of project setup/dependency:

**Bundle "security.api"**

```
// JDO Persistent Class
public class User {
    // ... some code ommitted ....
    public String getUserId();    
    // ... some code ommitted ....
}
```

**Bundle "app.api"**

```
// JDO Persistent Class
public class UserSubClass extends User {

}

// App Logic Facade (OSGi Service Intf)
public interface MyAppFacade {
    // ... some code ommitted ....
    public UserSubClass createUserSubClass(UserSubClass account);
    // ... some code ommitted ....
}
```

**Bundle "app.impl"**

```
// Facade/OSGi Service Impl
public class MyAppFacadeImpl implements MyAppFacade {
    // ... some code ommitted ....

    public UserSubClass createUserSubClass(UserSubClass account) {

        // Eclipse java editor will report: 
        // "The method getUserId() is undefined for the type ...."
        account.getUserId(); 

    }

    // ... some code ommitted ....
}
```

**As you can see in this image:**

[image: Could not call method inherited from super class]

The variable `account` in the image above is an instance of class `UserSubClass` in which that it extends `User`. So, I'm expecting that we could call method `getUserId()` as it should be, but, we couldn't. *Eclipse Java Editor* will report error:

"The method getUserId() is undefined for the type UserSubClass", as shown in the image.

The more weird thing is ... it seems that the java compiler can see `getUserId()` method inherited from class `User`, nor, it is **NOT reported as an error** in *Project Explorer* and I can compile & build the bundle jar file normally!

I'm guessing that it might be an issue between **Datanucleus Enhancer vs Eclipse Java Editor** since **all of my bundle jars are enhanced at build time**.

This problem happens only if the *Bnd Build Path* points to the released bundle jar in repository cache, which is a JDO already-enhanced version.

To say more clearly, if the *Bnd Build Path* is pointing to depending bnd project directly (putting `;version=latest` after the depending bundle symbolic name, for example, `security.api;version=latest` & `app.api;version=latest`), this problem will go away.

At the beginning of the project, I'm not facing this situation because all of *Bnd Build Path*s are pointed to the bnd project directly. But, at this time, the project is a lot more expanded and developed, we currently have 50+ bundles. So, we decided to release all stable bundles into the repository and let everyone import from it. This helps us reduce a lot of compilation time when you restart Eclipse (you don't need to wait for datanucleus enhancer to enhance all of your classes from low-level stable bundles up to the top all over again).

**My workarounds (none of these is working):**

- Try to attach source code to the bundle jar in `.classpath` file.
- Try to distribute source code along with the bundle jar in `OSGI-OPT/src` folder.
- Try to upgrade Eclipse (Oxygen) and Datanucleus (v5) to the newest one.
- Try to clean & build projects entirely (like creating a new workspace and setup the env from scratch).

**!!! EDIT !!!** Decompiled version of `User` & `UserSubClass`

Decompiled version of class `User`:

[image]

You can see that it ACTUALLY CONTAINS `getUserId()` method. And, it is a *JDO Enhanced* version because the method content is delegating method call to `dnGetuserId(this)`.

Decompiled version of class `UserSubClass`:

[image]

You can see that it ACTUALLY EXTENDS class `User`. And, it is a *JDO Enhanced* version because the interface `Detachable` and `Persistable` is automatically injected by the enhancer from `@PersistenceCapable` annotation.

PS. I don't think that it is the problem of *JDO Enhancer* nor *Java Compiler* (javac) since there is nothing wrong noticeable in decompiled version of enhanced classes, and, as I mentioned earlier, I can compile & build the bundle jar file normally!

The only weird thing is:

**WHY ECLIPSE JAVA EDITOR COULD NOT SEE METHODS INHERITED FROM THE JDO ENHANCED SUPER CLASS?**

Comment: You don't say what is "account" in "this image", and why the method `getUserId` would be a problem. Clearly if you think enhancement is a problem you can look at Java-decompiled classes and verify what you think.

Comment: Thanks Billy, I've edited the post as you suggested. I'll post another reply for the java-decompiled class find out in minutes.

Comment: The decompiled version of enhanced classes find out has been added.